# How to forward ssh-agent/gpg-agent from a web browser app?

Tags: browser, remote-access, gnupg

I want to allow a server to perform local (to the server) ssh and gpg operations on client request using client's secret keys stored on client's machine.

Client's secret keys are managed by native GnuPG and/or OpenSSH installations, nor by the browser (SmartCard and ssh-forwarding support is required).

Client access the server through a conventional web browser. No other communication channel different from those offered by a major browser are allowed.

Is there any solution to forward ssh-agent/gpg-agent through a web browser app to a remote system?

Comment: Have you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Sending client's secret keys to the server to perform local ssh/gpg operations look like a security issue to me.
But you can contact client's gpg from the browser using [Native Messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging). I would look in that direction. It would involve writing a browser extension, though.